# InvalidArgumentException: Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ExecuteSolutionController not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I'm trying to do the Dusk testing.

`ViewAnotherUsersTweetsTest.php`

```
/**     
     * @test
     */
    public function can_view_another_users_tweets()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create(['username' => 'johndoe']);

        // make() stores in memory
        $tweet = factory(Tweet::class)->make([           
            'body' => 'My first tweet'
        ]);


        $user->tweets()->save($tweet);

        $this->browse(function ($browser) {
            $browser->visit('/johndoe')
            ->dump();
        });        
    }
```

Route in web.php : `Route::get('{username}', 'UserController@show');`

`UserController.php`

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function show(string $username) {        
        $user = User::findByUsername($username); // ExecuteSolutionController not defined.
        dd($user);
   }
}
```

in `App\User.php` model file

```
public static function findByUsername($username) {
 return self::where('username', $username)->first(); 
}
```

When I execute the test with command `php artisan dusk --filter can_view_another_users_tweets`, it fails and shows following error message.

`(1/1) InvalidArgumentException Action Facade\Ignition\Http\Controllers\ExecuteSolutionController not defined.`

What could be the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can we see the findByUsername function? There is clearly somewhere your code cant find ExecuteSolutionController.

Comment: @mrhn updated the question with the function